# django templates not showing objects

Tags: python, django

hi i m trying to pass data from my models but it does not show anything..

it is rendering {{Experience.first.Designation}} but  {{Experience.Designation}} is showing nothing.. also if i use {{Experience.first.Designation}} it will ony show one row of database in for loop repetedly which i dont want

```
 {% for queryset in Experience %}
                            <li class="{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}timeline-right{% else %}timeline-left{% endif %}">
                                <div class="timeline-badge">
                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>

                                    <p class="{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}date-inverted wow {% else %}date wow {% endif %}">{{Experience.first.FromDate}} -{{Experience.first.ToDate}}</p>

                                </div><!-- end timeline-badge -->
                                <div class="timeline-panel wow slideInRight">
                                    <div class="experience-content">
                                        <h4>{{Experience.Designation}}</h4>
                                        <h5>{{Experience.Department}}</h5>
                                        <p>{{Experience.ShortNote}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--end timeline-panel -->
                            </li><!-- end timeline-right -->
                         {% endfor %}
```

here is views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from home.models import *
from django.views.generic import ListView

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
abt = About.objects.all()
return render(request,'home/index.html',{'abt': abt.first()})

def Experience(request):
Exp = Experience.objects.all()
return render(request,'home/Experience.html',{'Exp': Exp})

class MyView(ListView):
context_object_name = 'name'
template_name = 'home/index.html'
queryset = About.objects.all()

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['Experience'] = Experience.objects.all()
    context['About'] = self.queryset
    return context
```

here is models.py

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
# Create your models here.
class About(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'pics')
desc  = models.TextField()



class Experience(models.Model):


Designation = models.CharField(max_length=150)
Department = models.CharField(max_length=150,default='my dept')
Organisation =models.CharField(max_length=150)
ShortNote   = models.CharField(max_length=200)
FromDate  = models.DateField( default=datetime.date.today)
ToDate = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

def __str__(self):
    return self.Designation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `{% for x in y %}` you need to use `x` within the loop to refer to the current item you are looping over, so if you use `for queryset in Experience` you need to use `{{ queryset.Experience }}`, `{{ queryset.Department }}`, etc.

However, I wouldn't use the name `queryset` here, since a queryset is something different in Django, namely a set of database rows. `Experience` is the actual queryset in your template. You could use `for item in Experience` instead, and then use `{{ item.Experience }}`, `{{ item.Department }}`, etc. But that is up to you of course.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending Exp through render not Experience .
Try loop through Exp.

`for queryset in Exp`